# Libre Office Calc, User-defined Number format permille

Tags: format, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice

I know that LibreOffice allows you to define custom number formats.
I have a spreadsheet that displays some smallish percentages (all are less than 1%).
I would like to use permille **‰** instead.

Percentages less than one percent cause confusion with people looking at the spreadsheet as percentages are often interchanged with decimals 0.34 -> 34%. I've often seen spreadsheets where .34% was written and people have assumed this meant 34%, also I've seen cases where the author meant 34% but the value in the cell was .0034

I looked at the Format code for percent to see if there was any special trick I could use, since for a percentage the decimal point is moved 0.5 -> 50%, which is different from changing the thousand separator or the number of decimal places.

The "Format code" for percent looks like this: `0.00%`

It looks like the % symbol has a special interpretation and I can't just tell the format to multiply by 1000 and append the permille symbol
as a work-around I am using

```
=ROUND({originalCell}*1000,2)&"‰"
```

but this changes the value and makes the cell mixed number/text. Is there any way I can create a custom format for this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to do this with **just** the number format, but combining your workaround with the number format should solve the problem.

Adjust your workaround like so, leaving off the permille symbol:

```
=ROUND({originalCell}*1000,2)
```

Then use the permille symbol in the number format using quotes, like below.

```
0.00"‰"
```

That should keep the cell contents in number format while appearing with the permille symbol.

Comment: That's a slight improvement, at least I can have just a number this way. The value will still be out by a factor of 1000. In my version of Libre-office you can define the format as 0.00‰ (without quotes).